# Play framework Application installation

Tags: scala, playframework

I need to host and run  my play application in a normal pc not in a server. what are the things(software/applications) I need to install  in that pc and Is it possible to to? and I know Play has  in-build Netty Server. Please help me to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have the application to run on a PC I assume somebody has compiled and packaged the application for you. There are several ways how a Play app can be packaged.

For example if it has been packaged as a ZIP file, unzip it on the PC to an empty directory. It should then contain directories like `bin`, `conf`, `lib` and maybe more. The `bin` directory contains a file with the ending `.bat`. Run this file, e.g. `C:\appdirectory\bin\appname.bat`.

Make sure that the PC has the required Java Runtime Environment installed (e.g. Java 8).

You can find further instructions in the [Play documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Production).

Answer (score 0):

Activator is the one click installation tool to install play framework on your machine : http://www.lightbend.com/activator/download

Comment: No I just need to run application. I don`t need to develop a code.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want activator, then you can just go to https://www.playframework.com/download, and download a previous version of Play that comes without the activator.

Then, you can open the directory of the application, and run it:

```
$ cd /path/to/any/application
$ play 
$ run
```

But this is pretty much the same thing as using activator.